# what does (x..x).map do in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

Been looking at some kotlin examples on the web and saw the following, where i can not figur eout exactly what it's doing.

`(0..6).map{ inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container) }`

I know it's a range that inflates R.layout.test into container but what is the point of ".map" ?

is it just a different way to write `for (i in 0..6)` ?

Comment: it will return a list of `View`s from `layout/test.xml`

Comment: could you please share the link where you found this

Comment: @Charu https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/simplemobiletools/calendar/fragments/WeekFragment.kt

Line 82, i changed the inflater.inflate line to make it smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linked code it's just a different and not quite idiomatic way to repeat some action.

One can use the following approaches instead of `map` function, if the result of the transform is not gonna be used:

```
// for loop
for (n in 0..6) inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container)

// forEach extension
(0..6).forEach { inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container) }

// repeat function
repeat(7) { inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container) }
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` transforms the input into an output. Since Kotlin can infer the argument if it's the only one it will be called `it`. So your code is equivalent to this:

```
(0..6).map{ it => inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container) }
```

You can see that you are not using `it` argument anyways

So after doing that you will have a list of 7 views (from 0 to 6) inflated from `R.layout.test`

You can find more about `map` in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is a `Lambda` expression. It just inflate **R.layout.test** and add this view to the **container**. The example you are refering is a `GridView` and need to add this view 7 times in the container, that is what (1..6) doing here.